# Is there anyway to define placeholders for types rather than tf.dtypes in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

The definition of placeholder is

```
tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=None, name=None)
```

but I was wondering is there anyway to put other types of data in the placeholder, instead of dtype data?

In my case, I want to put a list of python strings in this placeholder, but I can only put tf.string, which is difficult to use for later processes. In addition, I can't find a way to transform tf.string to python string.

Anyone can help? Thx!!